# Derivative of an exponential matrix that involve trace operator

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-equations

I know this is a stupid question, but I got this weird doubt. Then I need to derive this expression with respect to each element of the $\Sigma$ matrix

$$
\varphi(t) = \exp\big(Tr[A(t)\Sigma] + C(t)\big)
$$

Now if I use the property $\mathrm{det}[\exp(A)] = \exp(Tr[A])$ and the fact that trace is a linear operator, in theory the result should be that for each element $ij$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Sigma_{ij}} \varphi = 
\exp\big(Tr[A(t)\Sigma] + C(t)\big) \times a_{ij} = 
\varphi \times a_{ij}
$$

with $a_{ij}$ an element of the matrix $A$, It is correct right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\g{\gamma}  \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\LMR#1#2{\left[ #1 \middle| #2 \right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Let's use a convention wherein an uppercase letter represents a matrix,
lowercase a vector, and a Greek letter will denote a scalar.

Next, I'll assume that $C(t)$ is a scalar (since you're
adding it to a trace which is a scalar valued function) so let's assign it a greek name $\:C\to\g.\;$ And let's rename the matrix $\:\Sigma\to S.$

The matrix inner product (denoted by a colon) is extremely useful and
has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
I:A &= \trace{A} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
Finally, for typing convenience define the matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
X &= \LR{AS + \frac{\g I}{n}} \;\in\; \R{n\times n} \\
\trace X &= \trace{AS} + \g \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the logarithm of your function and calculate its gradient wrt $S$
$$\eqalign{
\log(\psi) &= I:X \\
\frac{d\psi}{\psi} &= I:dX = I:\LR{A\,dS} = A^T:dS \\
d\psi &= \psi A^T:dS \\
\grad{\psi}{S} &= \psi A^T \qiq \grad{\psi}{S_{ij}} = \psi A_{ji} \\
}$$

Comment: what a wonderful answer, I could not have asked for anything more, thank you a lot (^_^)